# Why is my webcam not working on VMplayer 6.0.1?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualization, webcam, vmware-player

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop with the following configuration:

- Model: i5-3575
- 3.7 GiB of RAM
- Intel Core i5 4200 CPU @1.60 GHz X4
- Intel Haswell Mobile Graphics
- 350 GB hard drive
- Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

I have a virtual machine running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (with the latest updates).

My problem is that the webcam is not working in the virtual machine. How can I get it to work? It's working fine on the host OS.

Comment: The title of your question says "VMplayer" (so presumably VMWare Player), but you've tagged it with "virtualbox". Which one are you using? Also, in what way is the webcam not working? Does it show up in the guest machine's Device Manager? Do you get any error messages, either on the host or the guest OS?

Comment: @Indrek I have corrected the tag ,cam is showing in the device manager in the guest machine but the cam is not working in any apps like teamviewer,skype ,google hangout etc.

Comment: Have you connected the webcam to the virtual machine? In the Player window, click the double arrow to show devices, then find the one corresponding to your webcam, right-click on it and select "Connect (Disconnect from host)". Also, does the Win7 guest machine have the proper drivers installed? Double-click the webcam in Device Manager and check the device status, it should say "This device is working properly".

Comment: @Indrek Yes i have already did that , also the proper drivers are already installed/updated and it is showing that "This device is working properly".